# Java: Passing an Enumeration to a Method

Tags: java

This is my question .

I am working on a Third Party API whose return value is of type Enumeration.

So I am passing the Enumeration result to a method as shown below

Please let me know if this is valid code or not?

```
private Data loadData(Enumeration rs, Data data) 
{
while (rs.hasMoreElements()) 
{
// Process it 
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is valid. `Enumeration` is a normal Java type and you pass an instance of the `Enumeration` class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Enumeration is a valid type in java and you can use as normally as other data type.